# Is there a way to mention red green blue to detect perfectly

Tags: python, pyautogui

How do I tell pyautogui to read RGB then click on the pixel?

I have to detect RGB and then click because of random clicking everywhere, I don't understand what happens it has to click on snapchat via teamviewer, and send snaps to people

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

#Title 1 Position: 1139 Y:  865 RGB: (  0,   0,   0)
#Title 2 Position: 1126 Y:  806 RGB: (  4,   4,   4)
#Title 3 Position: 1249 Y:  869 RGB: (255, 255, 255)
#Title 4 Position: 1116 Y:  557 RGB: ( 84,  88,  93)
#Title 5 Position: 1299 Y:  863 RGB: (  0, 168, 255)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.50)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(1139, 865)[0] == 0:
        click(1139, 865)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1126, 806)[0] == 4:
        click(1126, 806)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1249, 869)[0] == 255:
        click(1249, 869)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1116, 557)[0] == 84:
        click(1116, 557)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1299, 863)[0] == 0:
        click(1299, 863)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand what your code is doing, but here's how you can check the RGB color of pixels:

```
x, y = 100, 100
rbg_tuple = pyautogui.pixel(x,y)
if rbg_tuple == (255,255,255):
    pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

That code checks if the pixel at coordinates 100, 100 is white and clicks on it if it's true. Hope that's what you needed.

Comment: Thank you thats what I needed! My code was checking only R because it was 0 over there